# ElasticSearch multiple string to search with wildcard query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to have multiple wildcard query match in my elasticsearch query in Kibana. I can't quite figure it out.

Basically I want any document with an attribute type="erreur"

and I want to exclude all documents that match the strings "An established*" or "java.lang.*" on the field descr_courte

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "type": "erreur"
        }
  },
      "must_not": {
        "wildcard": {
          "descr_courte": ["An established*", "java.lang.*"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if I put a single wildcard query it works fine

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "type": "erreur"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "wildcard": {
          "descr_courte": 
            "An established*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the error I get:

Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:454"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards 
Any idea?

Comment: so, what's not working?

Comment: Have you tried that query? Have you tested it on your application?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Try putting them is separate clauses.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "type": "erreur"
        },
        "must_not": [
          {
            "wildcard": {
              "descr_courte": "An established*"
            }
          },
          {
            "wildcard": {
              "descr_courte": "java.lang.*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you can't make an array for wildcard query like `["An established*", "java.lang.*"]`, so you need to:

```
{
 "query": {
    "{
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "type": "erreur"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "regexp": {
          "descr_courte": "(An established|java\.lang\.).*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More info about regexp query in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Another option is to combine your query terms with the logical operators `NOT`, `AND` and `OR` in the query string

```
{
 "query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "type:erreur AND NOT(descr_courte:An established* OR descr_courte:java.lang.*)"
    }
  }
}
```

See more info at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards

Comment: I get a "Duplicate Key" warning then when I save the filter, Kibana just discard the first "wildcard" clause

Comment: @Dom I've just updated the answer to a bool query, have you tried thsi way?

Comment: @Dom you can still use a simple query with a more complex regex for the query string

Comment: Thanks it works. Not optimal because I need to enter like 20 strings to exclude in my REGEX but at least it works.

Comment: @Dom glad it helped, I found another option which is to combine several terms in the query string with `AND` operator

Comment: Thanks gain 2nd solution is much better in term of maintenance and readability